# Passing form as parameter when creating new form

Tags: c#, winforms, parameters

I have a MainForm, which is MDI container. In MainForm, I create 2 new forms, which open on buttonclick - Form1 and Form2. And there is also a 3rd form - CommonFom, which I should be able to open from Form1, and Form2 (on buttonclick). I need 3rd Form to save info if I switch between Form1&2, so I cant create new instances of it from Form1&2.
I'm trying to do something like this in MainForm:

```
CommonForm CF = new CommonForm();
Form1 x = new Form1(CF);
Form2 y = new Form2(CF);
```

after that, in Form1 and Form2:

```
public MainForm(CommonForm theCF)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
```

... somewhere on buttonclick

```
CF.show();
```

But it show me error in Form1, than there is no instance of object CF (in line CF.Show())
So how do I do this correctly?

Comment: Was going to suggest using the My.Forms application framework, which handles common forms fantastically, but C# doesn't seem to support that!

Comment: Pretty unclear.  Why are you not storing the *theCF* argument value in the constructor?  Where *exactly* is the Show() call located?  Improve your snippets.

Answer (score 2):

Declare in Form1 and Form2 in the beginning. (since it is missing in the code, I'm not sure about compile error or runtime error)

```
private Form CF; //The reason I've declared the type as Form is to have flexibility of having any form to show.
```

Modify each of the constructors of Form1 and Form2 like this.

```
public MainForm(CommonForm theCF)     
{   
    this.CF = theCF; 
    InitializeComponent();        
}
```

it should solve your problem.

Comment: Now I have this error - Error 1 A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'mhmm.MainForm.CF' This is in line Form1 x = new Form1(CF);

Comment: use `this.CF` instead of `'mhmm.MainForm.CF`

Comment: Sorry I dont understand. I'm not using mhmm.MainForm.CF anywhere. That was just errorcode. A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'mhmm.MainForm.CF'

Answer (score 0):

Use the `CommonForm` as a singleton: ie provide a `static` property `Instance` of type `CommonForm` inside the `CommonForm` class, instantiate it the CommonForm constructor. Then you can have everywhere access to CommonForm by using `CommonForm.Instance`.